# Dropdown with capital or small first letter?

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list

I just wonder, is there any statement what should (is more right) to use? Should dropdowns have capital first letter or small? Any article for use casesor some source or it doesn´t matter?

Comment: This is a matter of house style rather than UX. Your copywriters or content strategy team would be the right people to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that in most situations, it is appropriate to capitalize the menu options.

*Case 1*: The drop down is an answer to a question, so standard English grammar calls for a capital letter to begin a sentence<sup>1</sup>. **Capitalize.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy7IDZ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

<sub>1: The answers themselves might not technically be complete sentences, but they are colloquially understood to be complete responses.</sub>

---

*Case 2*: The drop down menu contains proper nouns ([as mentioned by @MattOKeefe](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/101260/77811)). **Capitalize.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5t7SH.png)</sup>

---

After thinking about it longer, I can't think of an argument for using all lowercase in drop down menus unless that's explicitly part of the style of your content/site/app.

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown contains a list of proper-nouns (people, places, things) then they should be capitalised. Even if your dropdown contains something else, capitalisation is likely to be right.

Comment: Can you cite any study references for these assertions?

Comment: Study reference are irrelevant, this is just standard English. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proper_noun

Comment: Study references are not irrelevant: "In most cases dropdowns will contain lists of proper-nouns" - What data are you basing this on?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect that.